# How to send a video via direct message on Instagram?

Tags: python-requests, instagram

It is possible for me to send direct messages on Instagram, however now I need to send a video to a specific person. I have no clue how to approach this. Furthermore, I found nothing on the web that could help me. I usually code in python, however all approaches are happily welcome!

The code I have for sending messages is the following:

```
def sendMessage(self, target_user, msgText):
    target_user = '[[{}]]'.format(','.join([target_user]))
    url = 'direct_v2/threads/broadcast/text/'
    data = {
        'text': msgText,
        '_uuid': self.uuid,
        '_csrftoken': self.token,
        'recipient_users': target_user,
        '_uid': self.username_id,
        'action': 'send_item',
        'client_context': self.generateUUID(True)}
    return self.SendRequest(url, data)
```

where SendRequest is taken from this unofficial Instagram-API: https://github.com/LevPasha/Instagram-API-python (and the function is also taken from another stackoverflow question)